# incrementing arrays and length

Tags: java, arrays

I am setting up a shop program. The code below is a method. The code includes setting up a shop and actually using the shop. Within this method, I am trying to figure out the discount a user gets based upon how many items a user buys.

When a user sets up a shop, they are able to set x amount of items to qualify for the discount.

For example, if a user buys 20 items, and x amount of items to qualify for the discount is set to 6 packs. The user would get (2 * the price of items) discount subtracted from the original price.

Every 6 packs the user gets 1 pack for free to a max of 20.

6 packs + 1 pack free + another 6 packs + one pack free + 6 pack = 20 packs.

I have tried to create loop such as subtracting the number of items a user wants to buy bought while counting value when modulo is 0 and subtracting from the amount that the user bought but I am getting nowhere close to it.

**Arrays were brought from other methods:**

`price[i]` is the price of the item
`buyItems[i]` is the number of items a user buys
`packs[i]` is the user choice of discount, for example, a user can set the 
discount to apply at 2 pack, 3 pack or even none.

```
public static void checkOuts(String [] names, double [] price,double [] packs,double addDiscount[], double[] buyItems, double[]addDiscountrate, int k ){

    double orgSub=0;
    double newSub=0;
    double addPercent=0;
    double specDis =0;
    double freePack=0;
    double disCheck =0;
    double count=0;

    for (int i =0; i < k; i++ ) {
        orgSub+=price[i]*buyItems[i];
    }

    System.out.println("Original Subtotal:             $" + orgSub);

for (int i =0; i < k; i++ ) {
    orgSub+=price[i]*buyItems[i];
}

System.out.println("Original Subtotal:             $" + orgSub);

for (int j = 0; j < buyItems.length; j++) {
    disCheck = buyItems[j];

    for(int d =0; d < buyItems.length; d++) {
        freePack = packs[d];

        for (int s =1; s < disCheck; s++)
            if (s % freePack==0) {
                count++;
                disCheck = disCheck -1;
                System.out.println(disCheck);
            }

    }
    specDis+= count*price[j];
    // the final discount that will be subtracted from original
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My version of your code (I removed things that were never explained):

```
public static void checkOuts(String[] names, double[] price, int[] packs, int[] buyItems) {

        System.out.println("Name\tnumFree\ttotalNum\tTotalPrice");
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            int numFree = buyItems[i] / (packs[i] + 1);
            double totalPrice = (buyItems[i] - numFree) * price[i];
            System.out.println(names[i] + "\t" + numFree + "\t" + buyItems[i] + "\t\t" + totalPrice);
        }

    }
```

When called with the following code:

```
String[] names = {"Coke", "Pepsi"};
double[] price = {1, 1};
int[] packs = {3, 4};
int[] buyItems = {10, 20};

checkOuts(names, price, packs, buyItems);
```

You get the following output: (Which is in line with your comments)

```
Name    numFree totalNum TotalPrice
Coke    2       10       8.0
Pepsi   4       20       16.0
```

You may also want to look into making your code object oriented. Rather than passing around parallel arrays, it would be easier to pass around a single array of items, or orders, which would have fields for name, price, discount, and anything else you needed.

Comment: You have misunderstood the question. The price[i], packs[i], and buyItems[i] does represents the index of items. However, There are multiple values stored in each array.   The buyItems[i] / (packs[i] + 1); does not give the number of discount it's suppose to give. 

For example, 
Coke is offered with buy 3 get 1 free special
discount and Pepsi is offered with buy 4 get 1 free special discount. So, with 10 packages of Coke, the
user gets 2 packages for free, and with 20 packages of Pepsi, the user gets 4 packages for free. This gives us
a total special discount of (2*10) + (4*30) = 140.

Comment: The free package is added into the total number of package the user wants to buy.

Comment: @IttyBittyStitch If the free items are added to the number of items the customer requested (in buyItems[i]), why does your original question state "6 packs + 1 pack free + another 6 packs + one pack free + 6 pack = 20 packs" instead of "6 packs + 1 pack free + another 6 packs + one pack free + 6 pack + one pack free = 21 packs"? 

Your math seems to suggest that the number of items purchased can't be changed by adding free items (even if the free item would already be earned)

Also, I 100% don't understand the total special discount math you posted at the bottom.

Comment: That's correct. "the number of items purchased can't be changed by adding free items (even if the free item would already be earned)". It would not be 21 but rather it would be 20. The user would get exact numbers of items of what they bought.

Comment: With that explanation, I'm still not sure why the buyItems[i] / (packs[i] + 1); code does not work. 
in the coke example, the state would be: buyItems[i] = 10; packs[i] = 3; and 2 = (int) 10/(3+1); so as you said, you would 2 for free. Also, should packs[i] really be a double? can you order fractions of items? because if so, my math will be off.

Comment: @IttyBittyStitch I've updated my answer to include code which I believe has the desired output. If not, please give me a set of valid inputs and outputs.

Comment: I went ahead and tested the code you provided within the loop. Sorry for misunderstanding your answers. 
 
It finally works!

Thank you so much for your help! I hope you have a wonderful day.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. 
If I have answered your question, could you mark it as "accepted"? (and possibly up-vote it) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why are all of these arrays? Aren't they just an amount?  (I may be misunderstanding)

If you do change these to integers, you can get the amount for free with

```
count = Math.floor(buyItems/packs);
```